# Programmatic Font Sizing in Delphi Fire Monkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to programmatically modify font sizes using the Fire Monkey library and nothing seems to work. Here is my latest attempt:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j, k: integer;
  w: single;
begin
  k := 0;
  with StringGrid1 do
  begin
    canvas.Font.Size := 24;                         //set font size
    StringColumn2.visible := false;                 //hide this column
    for i := 0 to columncount - 1 do                //loop through columns
    begin
      columns[i].header := 'hdr' + inttostr(i + 1); //provide header content
      w := StringGrid1.Canvas.TextWidth(columns[i].header); //measure width needed
      for j := 0 to rowcount - 1 do                 //loop through rows
      begin
        k := k + 1;                                 //variable cell content
        if i = 0 then                               //do row label
          cells[i, j] := 'Lyr' + inttostr(k)
        else
        begin                                       //do row body
          cells[i, j] := inttostr(k);
        end;
        w := max(w, StringGrid1.Canvas.TextWidth(cells[i, j])); //measure width needed
      end;
      columns[i].Width := w + 10;                   //set width
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

`canvas.Font.Size := 24` has no effect on the font sizing, but there is an interesting side effect. Changing the font size changes the results provided by `canvas.TextWidth`. So, there is a partial implementation of the font sizing. For those who would suggest font styles, none are in effect for this problem. In an earlier exercise, I encountered a similar lack of response to changes in `font.size` for `TEdit` components, but I don't know if font styles were in effect for that exercise; I know I didn't set any.

Comment: Is this article of any help, [` 
Changing Cell Font Properties in the FireMonkey TStringGrid`](http://www.raize.com/Articles/FmxStringGridCellFonts.asp).

Comment: The change in the canvas properties are only temporary in your button event method. Setting the cell text and column width changes the grid properties, so these changes persists. Read the article I linked and see how to hook the style events when drawing the cell contents.

Answer (score 1):

In the **StringGrid1** properties you have **StyledSettings**. You must expand this property and set to **False** the Items you need to change.

In this case: **Size**.